# What exactly is the purpose of the hosted zone ID for ELB and Beanstalk and other services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

If I want to create a route53 alias record to an AWS service I also must specify the specific "Hosted zone". The hosted zone differs from ELB type to region and is different for beanstalk endpoints and other services: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

What are these hosted zones and why do I need to specify them manually (if selected via the UI it will add the alias with the zone for you)?

Why do I as a user need to know about these hosted zone IDs at all? I'm assuming there is a good reason why this isn't abstracted away from me, but I can't understand why. There is something integral to the way route53 works I'm unclear on, I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is something integral to the way route53 works I'm unclear on i suspect.

Yes, there is.

Aliases are not like CNAMEs -- they do not result in a second query to resolve the target.  They are *internal* pointers, inside Route 53, that tell the service "when you get a request for X, look up the value of Y *inside hosted zone Z* and return that answer."

A hostname does not necessarily uniquely map to a single Route 53 hosted zone.  Route 53 has (at last check) 2048 unique nameserver IP addresses, 4 of which are associated with any given hosted zone.  (That doesn't mean you have only 4 actual nameservers -- they are anycast addresses.)  As a consequence, you can go into Route 53 and create a hosted zone for essentially any domain name you like.  You can even create multiple public hosted zones for exactly the same domain.  As alarming as this sounds, it's harmless, because even though you can create them, you can't make use of them, because nobody will be querying them... Every hosted zone has a set of 4 unique nameservers that will never be associated with another hosted zone in a way that would result in an ambiguity.

So, an Alias is not simply a directive to look up another name.  It's a directive to look directly into another, specific hosted zone to find an answer.  The only zones that support this are the official service zones, or the same zone as the one where the alias is created (referencing another record in your zone).

They could have designed this differently, of course, but they didn't.  It seems possible that they originally designed this to solve a potential future scaling issue and planned to use more than one hosted zone per service per region, and that turned out not to be necessary as Route 53 evolved and expanded.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7022698. is this related to this? "Obvious question: Why don't we enable ALIASing across zones by default? Firstly, zones which can be aliased to have to be replicated and available in all shards of our partitioned datastore (some day we may use some kind of cross-shard query protocol to resolve that, but even then we'd prefer to minimize the traffic) and secondly we want to ensure some stability for ALIAS targets and avoid situations where targets may be discontinued or deleted by their owners leaving our mutual customers stranded."

Comment: So if I have a zone thats linked to a registered domain name and another hosted zone that i just create (not registered publicly) could I create an alias record from the registered zone to that other non public hosted zone? or by "official service zones" you mean just actual services like ELB, etc?

Comment: Right. Aliases can only link to the hosted zones for the services, like ELB, CloudFront, etc., or to other records in the same hosted zone (which becomes useful for complex routing and failover scenarios).  They can't link to other hosted zones in your account or to those in other accounts, except possibly by special configuration as noted in the HN post you found.

Answer (score 0):

`Hosted Zone Id`s are associated with `Route53 Public/Private Hosted Zone`. When your automation need to create a `recordset`, it has to know which `Hosted Zone` to create the record in. It will identify that by the `Hosted Zone Id` you provide.

Comment: I have to provide the service's hosted zone AND the DNS name of my endpoint which always already has the region in it, for example: `myapp.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. So why does route53 need both? cant it just figure out the region from the DNS name?

Comment: That is how it is implemented so I guess you need to provide that feedback to AWS. :)